# When using combine in SwiftUI to update a Lottie Animation, it fails to update at the right time and gives an unexpected result

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, lottie

I have this ViewModel that uses combine along with a timer and I want this ViewModel to update a LottieView and filename with a new animation. When the timer counts down I want it to publish and send specific strings, these strings will be the json Lottie filenames. When my ContentView receives these filenames I want it to dynamically update the LottieViews animation.

So I made an @State variable called name inside ContentView and made that equal to the received value that is passed in. However, what confuses me is that the filename that is being published and sent from the ViewModels timer at the 10 second mark is suppose to be received and used inside  LottieView(filename: name).

However this LottieView instantly runs this file when I launch the app. How so? The only place that filename exists in the whole app is when the timer reaches 10 seconds and it shouldn't even exist when LottieView(name) is called. It also ignores the previous file name that should have been run at the 19 second mark. If I were to ignore LottieView(name) all together and run a Text View instead, so in this case Text(name), when I run the app the Text properly changes when the timer reaches 10.

So how come LottieView(name) runs like this? I verified these files properly match their animations as well.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    var anyCancellable: AnyCancellable?
    let publish = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var scheduleTime = 20
    
    init() {
        fire()
        anyCancellable = publish.sink { str in
            print("Value that is being passed over: \(str)")
        }

    }
    
    func fire() {
        print("Fire timer")
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            
            
            self.scheduleTime -= 1
            print(self.scheduleTime)
            if self.scheduleTime == 19 {
                self.publish.send("13865-sign-for-error-flat-style")
            }
            if self.scheduleTime == 10 {
               self.publish.send("4174-unlock-to-premium")
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
}


import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel()
    @State var name: String = ""
    var body: some View {
      
        VStack {
            LottieView(filename: $name)
            Text(name)
        }
            .onReceive(vm.publish, perform: { value in
                print("passed over : \(value)")
                name = value
                print(name)
            })
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


import SwiftUI
import Lottie

struct LottieView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
  typealias UIViewType = UIView
  @Binding var filename: String
  
  func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) -> UIView {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    
    let animationView = AnimationView()
    let animation = Animation.named(filename)
    animationView.animation = animation
    animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    animationView.play()
    
    animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(animationView)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
      animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
      animationView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
      animationView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
    ])
    
    return view
  }
  
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) {
  }
    
}
```

[image: Console output when the code runs]

Comment: your issue is about using Lottie?

Comment: Yes I think that might be the case. When the @State name property is overwritten, I don’t understand why LottieView(filename: name) is not triggering a new animation.

Comment: However I did figure out recently that if I were to comment out the whole timer function, so those files were not called anywhere in my program, the animation would still run. That made me believe that the filename was somehow being cached inside the Lottie Dependency. So this was a fix to trigger the first animation.

If name = “” {
 LottieView(filename: $name)
}

Comment: I do not like Lottie and the way that works! It is still on UIKit and they charge you for silly code, wouldn't you ask them about your issue? I think at least they got the money, then they should give support as well, and lastly I do not know how you could even trust their product to putting that in your app, even it was free.

Comment: Would changing filename inside LottieView to `let filename: String` solve the issue?

Comment: When state is updated, it calls `updateUIView` of a `UIViewRepresentable`, which is empty in your case. That's why nothing is happening. Inside `updateUIView` is where you need to reset/restart the animation with the now-new filename

Answer (score 0):

After a day of searching, without finding an answer, I probably came up with a not very correct solution, but it seems to work(saving temp fileName and after update LottieView checked name):

```
import SwiftUI
import Lottie

struct LottieView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewType = UIView
    var filename: String
    var animationView = AnimationView()
    let isPaused: Bool
    var needUpdate: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if needUpdate {
                let animation = Animation.named(filename)
                animationView.animation = animation
                animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                animationView.loopMode = .loop
                animationView.play()
                needUpdate = false
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        
        let animation = Animation.named(filename)
        animationView.animation = animation
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animationView.loopMode = .loop
        
        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(animationView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor),
            animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
        ])
        animationView.play()
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieView>) {
        let tempFileName = context.coordinator.parent.filename
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            context.coordinator.parent.filename = filename
            if tempFileName != filename {
                context.coordinator.parent.needUpdate = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var parent: LottieView
        
        init(_ parent: LottieView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
    }
}
```